# Sort ruby array in descending order with nil values and multiple arguments

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, null

First, I have found posts to sort values with possibles nil values, other posts to sort decending, but I didnet find the solution with both.

Here is where I am:

```
@records = @records.to_a.sort_by do |r| [-r.optimized_all_count, [r.year ? 1 : 0, r.year]] end
```

This works very well, but I want the "year" comparator to be descending. I tested this:

```
-[r.year ? 1 : 0, r.year]
```

but the sign "-" won't work with nil values. I also tried `a.reverse`...

How do obtain the year argument descending (and keeping `-r.optimized_all_count` as first sorting argument), ideally:

```
2020, 2018, 2017...nil, nil, nil.
```

Thanks

Comment: `@records.to_a` – is there by chance a database query involved?

Comment: 'to_a' is not required, and yes, it was an AR database query.

Comment: Did you consider delegating the sorting to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@records = @records.to_a.sort_by do |r| [-r.optimized_all_count, [r.year ? 0 : 1, r.year ? -r.year : nil]] end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@records.to_a.sort_by { |r| [-r.optimized_all_count, -(r.year || -Float::INFINITY)] }
```

It's not clear if `.to_a` is required.

Comment: 'to_a' is not required in fact. Your solution is also working Cary, and shorter. Thanks.